# how to convert xml to document in java with escape single tags

Tags: xml, document, well-formed

there is some tags such `<img>` that their end-tag is optional.

```
String xml = "<div><img href=""></div>";
```

and not converted to document object through below code

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory =
DocumentBuilderFactory.    DocumentBuilder builder;
builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();  
Document doc = builder.parse(xml);
```

the error is

`The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message means exactly what it says. End tags in XML are not optional; your input is therefore not well-formed XML, and therefore the parser rejects it.

Comment: when I open the source of google.com there is some single tags and I cn`t parse it into document object. so how can I parse such google.com?

Comment: It looks more like HTML than XML to me, so try an HTML parser like validator.nu.

Comment: I didn`t know difference between XML and HTML. I wanted to parse HTML but used XML parser.thanks. the problem solved.